# Retrieving information from another package in Perl - Syntax

Tags: perl

I have a package called pack1::i1 and a package called pack2::i2. Inside pack2 there is a sub called foo. What would be the syntax for me to retrieve that sub from pack2 if I was in pack1?

Something like this?:

```
package pack1
sub hello {
   my $self = shift;
   my $x = pack2::i2->foo;
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the fully qualified name of the subroutine.
Here is an example.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

package Pack1::I1;

sub hello {
   my $self = shift;
   print Pack2::I2::foo(), "\n"; # fully qualified name
}

# sub is found because we are in namespace Pack1::I1
hello();

package Pack2::I2;

sub foo {
    return "foo from Pack2::I2::foo()";
}
```

However, the more common approach is the use the module *Exporter*. There you con export functions from the namspace Pack1::I1 to the namespace Pack2::I2.

Also please not the the convention is to capitalise namespaces.